# Why doesn't the dropdownlist selectindexchanged work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select

I have a dropdownlist, in which I added 3 items. And I want that when the first Item is selected, the text of a label to change... but it is not working!
Here is the code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dr = new DropDownList();
        if (dr.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {

            Label1.Text = "Good";
        }
        else if (dr.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {

            Label1.Text = "Bad";
        }

    }
```

First I have added the dropdownlist in the UpdatePanel and it didn't worked, so i thought maybe the updatePanel is making me this problem.
I removed the update panel, but stll it isn't working!!

Comment: dropdownlist's first item's index start from `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using it inside the selectedindexChanged event, then you don't need to initialize it further.

direcly use:

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {

        Label1.Text = "Good";
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {

        Label1.Text = "Bad";
    }

}
```

Comment: I think only part of the previous answer would be useful in the context, that states: If you don't have any item in the dropdown, then its selectedindex will be -1.

Answer (score 2):

You create new instance of dropdownlist, You have to use this dropdown which exists on your screen!

Check if your dropdown list has property AutoPostBack set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this line of code:

```
DropDownList dr = (DropDownList)sender;
```

And of course set the attribute AutoPosback to true for your dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

set **AutoPosback** property of dropdown to **true** at your aspx page. This will solve your problem.